# Proof for generalized sum of powers

Tags: number-theory, exponential-sum, bernoulli-numbers

Bernouli's Formula for sum of kth powers of first n natural numbers is given by: 
$$f_k(n)=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k{k+1\choose j}B_j(n+1)^{k+1-j}$$
where $Bj$ is the $j^{th}$ Bernoulli Number and is in a sense recursively given by:$$B_j=-\frac{1}{j+1}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}{j+1 \choose i}B_i$$.

I did find a generalized proof of this for Generalized case where powers can be complex numbers. I am looking for simpler proofs. Do you have any idea if this can be proved by induction.

Thank you.

PS. I am not sure of tags and appreciate if they are corrected.

**Added** By simpler I mean that do involve only integer powers.

Comment: Hint: use Gamma function evaluad on Gauss interger!

Comment: Section 7.6 of Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, has a proof *via* exponential generating functions that isn’t too ugly.

Comment: @Elias, I am not sure what you mean. I am not looking for proofs involving complex powers. and Brian, thanks, I will try to have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof using the generating function:
$$\frac{t}{e^t-1}$$
Can be found [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~pavel/bernoulli.pdf). In essence, the proof follows from noting that:
$$e^{kt}=\sum k^m \frac{t^m}{m!}$$
So that the sum $\ \sum k^m$ is related to the sum of the geometric series which is in turn related to the generating function.

Comment: And of course plant math has the proof as well:
http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofOfFaulhabersFormula.html